# How to add sharepoint out of the box web parts into page zone?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have created the SharePoint custom list.also created the custom page layouts with multiple zones.Programmatically I need to add this list into the page layout zone(c# - event receiver or page load).when the feature is activating, the list should add into zone automatically.please suggest an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for your requirement there is reference that you can refer to add custom webpart to webpart zone [Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86026/add-programmatically-custom-web-part-to-page-without-web-part-zone)