# Add web part to the Page Layout using JSOM or CSOM

Tags: web-part, csom, page-layout, jsom, web-part-gallery

I want to add the web part that is available in Web Part Gallery to the publishing page layout using CSOM or JSOM.

Comment: Can you use server object model?

Comment: Yes I Can. Share the code

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86026/add-programmatically-custom-web-part-to-page-without-web-part-zone

Comment: Above reference link for adding webpart in zone and getting the page layout.

Comment: Your question mentions adding a web part "...to the Page Layout..." which isn't the same as creating a page using a page layout and then adding a web part into a web part zone on that page. Are you looking to add a web part to a page layout (as a "default" web part, present when the layout is applied to a publishing page) or are you looking to drop a web part onto an existing publishing page?

Comment: Exactly!! I want to add the web part to the page layout not in publishing page..